# Advanced string parsing in python

Tags: python, regex

I've encountered a problem while trying to parse a complicated string. The string is really long and full of patterns but lets focus on what i need to take (and only that).

A substring from the huge string is:

> ... [span class=\"review-title\"]Wont open[/span] ***I have the GS5
>   and the game    wont open. I got this game when i got the first droid.
>   The fact that people havent been able to play since almost 2013 is
>   bull. Please fix this or there isnt a point in even having the game on
>   the server.*** [div class=\"review-link\" ...

Now I want to take the bold italic text, and i have the pattern, starts with [span class = ..]*[/span] ***desired text*** [div ... ] and this pattern repeates through the whole string.

How exactly do I take this specific text from the whole string and write it line after line?

Comment: Do you really want to parse this with regex? It looks like it's just HTML with the angle brackets changed into square brackets and the quotes escaped, and [the same reasons that make regex bad for HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) will almost certainly make regex bad for this language.

Comment: Actually, from a comment, it sounds like what you have really _is_ just HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern should fetch you the string, just grab the Group 1 value:

```
r'\[span\b[^]]*class=[\\"\']*review-title\b[^]]*][^[]*\[/span\]\s*([^[]*)\[div\b'
```

Or a more generic one that does not check the `class="review-link"`:

```
r'\[span\b[^]]*][^[]*\[/span\]\s*([^[]*)\[div\b'
```

Sample code at [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/YD1hlA):

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'\[span\b[^]]*][^[]*\[/span\]\s*([^[]*)\[div\b')
test_str = u"[span class=\"review-title\"]Wont open[/span] I have the GS5 and the game wont open. I got this game when i got the first droid. The fact that people havent been able to play since almost 2013 is bull. Please fix this or there isnt a point in even having the game on the server. [div class=\"review-link\" "
print re.search(p, test_str).group(1)
```

Output:

```
I have the GS5 and the game wont open. I got this game when i got the first droid. The fact that people havent been able to play since almost 2013 is bull. Please fix this or there isnt a point in even having the game on the server.
```

**EDIT**: Since the `[`s and `]`s are in fact `<`s and `>`s, here is [an updated regex and code](http://ideone.com/YD1hlA):

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'<span\b[^>]*>[^<]*</span>\s*([^<]*)<div\b')
test_str = u"<span class=\"review-title\">Wont open</span> I have the GS5 and the game wont open. I got this game when i got the first droid. The fact that people havent been able to play since almost 2013 is bull. Please fix this or there isnt a point in even having the game on the server. <div class=\"review-link\" "
print [x.group(1) for x in re.finditer(p, test_str)]
```

A [more specific regex](http://ideone.com/4KZhTp) to account for the `class` attribute:

```
p = re.compile(ur'<span\b[^>]*class\s*=\s*[\\\'"]*review-title[^>]*>[^<]*</span>\s*([^<]*)<div\b')
```

Comment: hey it works great but just a little thing im having trouble to solve, the original [, ] are <, >. couldnt write it in the post. can you rewrite the regex please?

Comment: works perfect, but when i run it on the whole text, it just gives me the first result.. i need to take all those texts and write them into a string or list of strings

Comment: Use `finditer`, I have updated the **EDIT** section and the links to the corresponding demo programs.

Comment: :-D Always glad to help people out. Time to go to bed for me. Happy programming!

Answer (score 1):

From your comments ("im having trouble to solve, the original `[`, `]` are `<`, `>`"), it's pretty clear that what you have is HTML.

[Do not try to parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

What you want here is an HTML parser. For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(huge_string)
for span in soup.find_all('span', class='review-title'):
    text = span.next_sibling
    print(text)
```

Even if what you have is HTML escaped in some way (backslash-escaped quotes, angle brackets turned into square brackets, etc.), you still don't want to parse it with regex. In that case, at most, you might want to use a regex as the preprocessor to turn it back into HTML to feed to an HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need just this regex:

```
(?<=\[/span\])[\s\S]*?(?=\[div)
```